# Microservice not Launching on Port Set by LaunchSettings.JSON

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, microservices

I'm trying to debug a Microservice.When running from VS,it launches in the port set in `LaunchSettings.json` ,but when running using the `exe` , all microservices starts from port `5001`.

```
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5004",
      "sslPort": 44345
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "myapp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5004",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: from what I understand, I believe, these ports only have meaning when debugging or running visual studio. they don't carry over to deployment (exe) file.

Comment: @Jay How to make the exe file use a specific port?

Comment: again, I am not a expert, so, this is a guess. but micro services, just like other services that work over internet, have default ports when they are deployed, and you cannot change them as they will clash with other default ports. on a localhost, you can control the ports because its your computer. but on the internet, it does not work that way. 

Further, why would you serve your service on a non-default port? What possible gain do you plan to make by it, other than confusing apps that want to consume your service because you decided to change the port. I don't get it.

Comment: @Jay There are several projects and i need to open VS and start them all to debug the application.This makes my machine slow,so i wanted to run the exe process only for debugging the Gateway(which i will open in VS).

Comment: then, your question should be updated. You are looking to debug your micro services by running it outside visual studio. Then, perhaps you can put your app in a Docker Container and run the app from Docker with a port that you want. That is what I would do.

Comment: @Jay Not familiar with Docker.. need to check on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222158/discussion-between-jay-and-techno).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kestrel server is configured to run dotnet core app on 5000 and 5001. But you can override it by providing command line argument --urls while executing  exe. You can read it more on [Setting Up Kestrel](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/december/setting-up-kestrel-port-in-configuration-file-in-aspnet-core/#:%7E:text=When%20running%20ASP.NET%20Core,proxy%20requests%20to%20port%205000.)

Alternate way to override default port is to run it from cmd.
Suppose your exe's name is webapi then to override default port open cmd and go to the folder where exe is located and run
**webapi.exe --urls http://localhost:port**. Port is integer value where kestrel will start listening.